# How to make this JDBC code more portable?

Tags: mysql, oracle, jdbc, portability

I have the following piece of code:

```java
List<List<Object>> batch = db.executeInsert("insert into Batches (batch_date,source,log_file,status) values (?, ?, ?, ?)", 
    now, 
    importZip.getAbsolutePath(), 
    logFile.getAbsolutePath(), 
    BatchStatus.IMPORTING.toString())
```

And the returned data when I run it on MySQL returns an Integer representing the inserted ID as expected. When run under Oracle it returns a non portable `ROWID` object. I have an identity column, which will be eventually be converted to a sequence that represents the ID.  However, there's not much you can do with the `ROWID`.

I've checked the code and I'm calling `statement.getGeneratedKeys()` which I thought was the whole point of making portable code. How can I write this in a portable fashion without executing things like `select from table where ROWID=?` which is clearly NOT portable.

Comment: Where is the `db.executeInsert()` method? Why are you asking questions about the behaviour of code you haven't posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the portable solution I found was to use a slightly different version of PreparedStatement and getGeneratedKeys().  This turned out to be portable across both mysql and oracle, and I imagine others:

```
Connection connection = createConnection();
PreparedStatement statement = null;
statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql,new String[] { "ID" });
int updateCount = statement.executeUpdate();

ResultSet keysRs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if( keysRs.next() ) {
    return keyRs.getInteger("ID");
}
```

This was the solution I used.

Comment: I am slightly surprised this works for Oracle, but good find! As I didn't know this feature worked on Oracle, I hadn't mentioned it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out, Oracle returns the `ROWID` so that you can - for example - obtain the id by querying the row.

Some databases return only the last generated id (which might not even belong to the table, eg MySQL AFAIK), some databases return only the id column as the first column in the `ResultSet`, others return **all** columns (eg PostgreSQL, Firebird by default) so the position of the id column might not necessarily be the first as it depends on the column order in the table.

The only real option is to create a database specific strategy that knows the rules to obtain the right column. This might involve firing off an extra query for Oracle, having some heuristic to find the primary key column for PostgreSQL and Firebird, etc.

Comment: So under the covers of the code of executeInsert() it's calling getGeneratedKeys() which I thought was the mechanism to make ID retrieval DB platform independent.  Why does it still require you write DB specific code to handle this situation?  If it doesn't do that then what's the point of getGeneratedKeys()?

Comment: @chubbsondubs In a perfect world you wouldn't need to write db specific code, but this isn't a perfect world and there simply are differences in the features supported by databases.